# Show / hide content recursively base on a delay

Tags: css, animation, hide, transition, show

I am wondering if there is a way in full CSS to reproduce the following animation (the tool-tip box that appears and disappears) and appears again.
I wanted it to be recursive

http://bourbon.io/

Comment: Please post your attempted code and research.

Comment: I have made few tests based on @Fabio advises http://codepen.io/Komagain/pen/MpKEaO. the animation is called poopinout

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using animations properties (with a custom animation).

Example:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="animatediv">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px;
}

#animatediv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: hideshow;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes hideshow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fabio1983/j6jj9766/

You can also check this page for more informations:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: Thank you Fabio for the example, a complementary question how can add a specific duration for the hide and one for the show?

Comment: @Komagain you could change percentages on keyframes... check updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fabio1983/j6jj9766/2/